# Update sql data from form and checkboxes

Tags: php, html, sql

I have created a form that update the data in a sql column, so far all good.
The problem I have is that I would like to choose what columns are going to be updated, with checkboxes.
So I want to categorize two files as movies, I just check the checkbox and write movies in the form.

But its not only that. Every column is already connected to a checkbox, but I use this checkbox with an delete query, so I can delete multiple rows.

So my question is more like, how can I combine this two function with "one" checkbox.

This is some of my code.

This is my table with the sql outputs, and with the delete button

```
<?php  
$files = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY `file_time` DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    ?>
<table id="table-3">
 <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Upload User</th>
            <th scope="col">Filename</th>
            <th scope="col">Upload date</th>
             <th scope="col">IP adress</th>
             <th scope="col">Category</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $files )) !==false)
{ 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>".$row['user_name'] . "</td> ";
?>
<td class="download"> <a href="download.php?file_id=<?php echo $row ['file_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></a></td>
<?php echo "<td>".$row['file_time'] . "</td> "; ?>
<?php echo "<td>".$row['file_ip'] . "</td> "; ?>
<?php echo "<td>".$row['category'] . "</td> "; ?>
<td>

<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="done[]" id="<?php echo $row['file_id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['file_id'] ?>">

</td>

<?php 
}
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"; 
 ?>
<input type ="submit" value ="Delete">
</form>
```

This form is the one with the update function

```
 <form action="function.php" method="post">
category: <input type="text" name="category" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and 
function.php

```
include('core/inc/init.inc.php');

    if(isset($_POST['category'])){
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE files SET category='$category'
    /*WHERE category='genom' */ ");

    header("Location: profile.php?uid=" . $_SESSION['uid']);
    }else{
    header("Location: profile.php?uid=" . $_SESSION['uid']);
    };
```

How can I combine these two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple submit buttons in the same form. So you can do something like this:

```
<?php  
    $files = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY `file_time` DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
<form action="updateordelete.php" method="post">
    <table id="table-3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Upload User</th>
                <th scope="col">Filename</th>
                <th scope="col">Upload date</th>
                <th scope="col">IP adress</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
        while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $files )) !==false)
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></td>
            <td class="download"> <a href="download.php?file_id=<?php echo $row ['file_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['file_name']; ?></a></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="file_time[<?php echo $row ['file_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['file_time']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="file_ip[<?php echo $row ['file_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['file_ip']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="file_category[<?php echo $row ['file_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['category']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="done[]" id="<?php echo $row['file_id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['file_id'] ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <input type ="submit" name="submittype" value = "Update">
    <input type ="submit" name="submittype" value = "Delete">
</form>
```

And then, in updateordelete.php:

```
if($_POST['submittype']=="Delete"){
   (do delete code...)
}elseif($_POST['submittype']=="Update"){
   (do update code...)
}
```

For each of the values, you can access them using $_POST['file_category']. For example:

```
$file_categories=$_POST['file_category'];
foreach($_POST['done'] as $file_id){
    echo $file_categories[$file_id];
}
```

Comment: Hey awesome tip I just entered everything in the same page.:) 
But i really don't know where I should put the text form so the values enters in the checkboxed column =/

Comment: I updated my answer to add a lot more detail. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hey I just solved it. :)

A little bit different than yours, but I couldn't have make it without you :)